# fade hidden div in and out with jquery

Tags: jquery, hidden, fadein, fadeout

i'm trying to fade a few hidden divs in on hover and out on mouse leave, but what seems to be happening is that the divs sort of flicker instead of just fading in.

initially when created the divs are hidden:

```
$(container).find('.myDiv').hide();
```

then i have 2 functions as follows:

```
function showDivs(container) {
    $(container).find('.myDiv').fadeIn('slow');
}

function hideDivs(bucketContainer) {
     $(container).find('.myDiv').fadeOut();
}
```

and this all put together as follows:

```
$('.container').live('mouseover', function() {
        showDivs(this);
});

$('.container').live('mouseout', function() {
        hideDivs(this);
});
```

How do i get rid of the odd flicker effect?

Comment: Give us a URL to see your page in action please?

Comment: Set this up on jsfiddle?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Can you try `mouseenter/mouseleave` instead of `mouseover/mouseout` ?

Answer (score 1):

my guess is that you execute the 'live' blocks

```
$('.container').live('mouseover', function() {
        showDivs(this);
});

$('.container').live('mouseout', function() {
        hideDivs(this);
});
```

more than one time.

If you do so you add up many mouseover, mouseout events on your DOM objects because jQuery is not replacing the live binds but stacking them.

So for example if you by accident run your live blocks 10 times, then with every mouseover, your live('mouseover') ... will be called 10 times.

That might look like flickering :-)

Comment: thanks all, mouseenter and mouseleave seems to do the trick. yup, mouseover and mouseout and live gets a bit tricky, the flicker is gone, thanks!

Answer (score 1):

jQuery API:

mouseover/mouseout event types can cause many headaches due to event bubbling. For instance, when the mouse pointer moves over the Inner element in this example, a mouseover event will be sent to that, then trickle up to Outer. This can trigger our bound mouseover handler at inopportune times. See the discussion for [.mouseenter()](http://api.jquery.com/mouseenter/) for a useful alternative.